# How to get data from Back end in to 2 dimenstional array and send array to javascript array and display

Tags: javascript, php

I want to display my data from backend into specified format in javascript.
I am getting the data from backend but echo json_encode($myarry) not displaying my data

```
        $query = "SELECT * FROM LOCATIONS";
        $result= mysql_query($query);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        { 

                    $latitude = (string)$row['latitude'];
                    $longitude = (string)$row['longitude'];

                    $myarry[] = "[$latitude,$longitude]";


        }
echo json_encode($myarry)
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var locations[] = <?php echo json_encode($myarry); ?>;
        </script>
```

I want my data to display like below in javascript

---

### var locations = [[17.02416, 81.01261],[ 17.59704, 81.08400],[17.07989, 81.08090], [16.58028, 81.40142],[16.9514482, 81.6921825]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example made for you, work as your expected. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/09b2c810d4560768bbc19d21909fbe14e5eedfc2

For your example code it would be:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM LOCATIONS";
    $result= mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    { 

                $latitude = (float)$row['latitude'];
                $longitude = (float)$row['longitude'];

                $myarry[] = [$latitude,$longitude];


    }
    echo json_encode($myarry)
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations[] = <?php echo json_encode($myarry); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not do `json_encode()` again on `$myArray`

```
    echo json_encode($myarry)

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var locations = <?php echo $myarry; ?>;
        localtions = JSON.parse(locations);
```

Just `parse` the JSON and it will be a array in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In your php file modify like this:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM LOCATIONS";
    $result= mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    { 
                $latitude = (string)$row['latitude'];
                $longitude = (string)$row['longitude'];
                $myarry[] = "[$latitude,$longitude]";

    }
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>var locations[] = " . json_encode($myarry)."</script>";
```